# getting wrong data value from last li in ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get the data-id value from the last li in the ul.  It always returns empty.

**js :**

```
var ss_id = $('#lightSlider .slides').last().data('id');
```

**ul/li structure :**

The same li structure repeats with different data.

```
<ul id="lightSlider" class="gallery list-unstyled clearfix lightSlider csSlide" style="width: 1124px;">
    <li class="slide active" title="(window has no title) " data-thumb="/showimage.php?show=test1.jpg" data-id="30" style="width: 1094px; float: left; margin-right: 30px;">
        <img class="img-responsive" title="(window has no title) " src="/showimage.php?show=test1.jpg">
        <div style="border-top:1px #dddddd solid; padding:0 15px 15px 15px; background:#f5f5f5;">
            <h4><b>Wed, 06/25/14 @ 4:58:24 am UTC</b></h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><b>1 :</b> test</li>
                <li><b>2 :</b> test</li>
                <li><b>3 :</b> test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have no element with the class of `slides` so far as I can see here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a simple mistake: try .slide class instead of .slides

```
var ss_id = $('#lightSlider .slide').last().data('id');
```